# How to define factory methods in Groovy/Grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, factory

I buid a factory in groovy, this code works, but I think, this code can be improved (or reduced) :

```
abstract class Processing {

    abstract getDirName();

    abstract getFileType();

    abstract moveFile();

    abstract processFile();

    abstract openFile();

    abstract closeFile();
}


class ProcessingBuilder {

    def processingFactory

    def orderProcess(String type) {

        def process = processingFactory.buildProcessing(type);

        process.getDirName();
        process.getFileType();
        process.moveFile();
        process.processFile();
        process.openFile();
        process.closeFile();

        return process;
    }

}

class ProcessingFactory {

      def buildProcessing(String type) {

        def process = null;

        if (type == "nanostring") {
            process = new ProcessingNanoString();
        } else if (type == "flowcore") {
            process = new ProcessingFlowCore();
        }
        return process;
    }

}

class ProcessingFlowCore extends Processing {

    def getDirName() {
      println "--> Get FlowCore directory structure"
    }

    def getFileType() {
      println "--> Get FlowCore File Type"
    }

    def moveFile() {
      println "--> Move FlowCore Files"
    }

    def processFile() {
      println "--> Import FlowCore files to DB"
    }

    def openFile() {
      println "--> Open FlowCore files"
    }

    def closeFile() {
      println "--> Close FlowCore files"
    }

}
```

To use this factory :

```
def processingFactory = new ProcessingFactory();

def processingBuilder = new ProcessingBuilder(processingFactory : processingFactory);

def process = processingBuilder.orderProcess("flowcore");
```

Is there a better way to build a factory with groovy/grails ?

I also experiment errors, if I try to use services in my ProcessingFlowCore Class : ex :

```
class ProcessingNanoString extends Processing {

  def directoryToolsService

    def getDirName() {
      println "--> Get NanoString directory structure"

      def dir = directoryToolsService.findDirPathByName(nanostring).directoryPath

      return dir
    }
```

I get a : ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Cannot invoke method findDirPathByName(nanostring) on null object.(I can call this service if I'm not in the factory).

Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick answer on the last part.   You only get service injection in certain places in the app (Controllers, Services, maybe one or two more).  You won't get the service injected in Domains, or classes created in src/groovy.

Comment: @Bill - domain classes are injectable by default, and I'm pretty sure that any classes in src/groovy are also injectable though the latter may require some configuration

Comment: I try to move my factory method part to /services, but I get the same error. In my folder services, I should get service injection.

Comment: My service is not injected via "def directoryToolsService", when I check with a debugger I get : directoryToolsService=null.

Comment: @Bill services get injected into Domain classes, but only if they are marked as transient (e.g. `static transients = ['directoryToolsService']`) so GORM knows it's not a persistent field.

Comment: Thanks all... I noticed service injection didn't work with Domains, but now see it can... however, it still doesn't work everywhere, which seems to be the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class using your service is in src/groovy, then it won't be injected automatically.  Services are only injected automatically into artefact classes (e.g. anything under grails-app).  To get a service from a regular class, get a reference to it manually with this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

service = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext().getBean('directoryToolsService')
```